# Create dialog in ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, dialog

I have an activity which extends from `ActonBarActivity` from the support library.

Now I want to add a dialog in this activity, and following the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) it seems that I have to use the `DialogFragment` as the dialog container:

> These classes define the style and structure for your dialog, but you
>   should use a DialogFragment as a container for your dialog. The
>   DialogFragment class provides all the controls you need to create your
>   dialog and manage its appearance, instead of calling methods on the
>   Dialog object.

Then there is no way to make my activity extends `DialogFragment`.

And I know the `Activity` itself own a `onCreateDialog(int id)` method, but it is deprecated, I wonder what's the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new class that extends `DialogFragment`, override its `onCreateDialog()` method with the code that creates an `AlertDialog`, and then instantiate that class inside your `Activity` and call `show()` on it to make it appear.