# Create AlertDialog in ActionBarActivity

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-actionbaractivity

I'm rebuilding my MainActivity that previously extended Activity. Now that it extends ActionBarActivity (rebuild app from scratch), i'm having trouble building an AlertDialog. This is how I did it previously:

```
final AlertDialog mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle("Change PIN")
            .setView(content)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    currentPIN = mEditText.getEditableText().toString();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                        }
                    }).create();
```

now that my Activity extends ActionBarActivity, how do I do this? My specific problem is that now the method getActivity() is undefined for the type MainActivity. I found this other question that was answered, but doesn't make much sense to me:

[Create dialog in ActionBarActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20159389/create-dialog-in-actionbaractivity)

Help por favor

Comment: can you see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `MainActivity.this` instead of `getactivity()`